# Identify iphone's version

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I'm developing an app which can only be installed in iPhone 4 and later versions.I also go through **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and Device Compatibility Matrix**.I need more solution.

Comment: Are you saying you only want your app to work on iPhone devices, not iPods or iPads?

Comment: @NimitParekh that seems a bit unnecessary as you can set a target OS version in your build settings. I think he's talking about removing support for a specific device.

Comment: This is probably a Bad Idea. Apple has their compatibility matrix to decide which devices an app is compatible with; if they find out that you're checking the device at run time and then (I assume) quitting the app, they'll probably pull it from the store. That's a bad user experience.

Comment: For iPhone 5S & 5C platform string, see this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854244/what-is-platform-string-for-iphone-5s-5c/18900927#18900927

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all you can receive the model as a string using the `UIDevice` class:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]
```

This will return something like "iPod touch" or "iPhone".

You can get the exact model platform using the following code:
(you have to `#include <sys/types.h>` and `<sys/sysctl.h>`)

```
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *machine = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *platform = @(machine); // Old syntax: [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
free(machine);
```

Now `platform` is a string containing the generation of the device, e.g.:

- `iPhone1,1` for the **iPhone 2G** (the first iPhone)
- `iPhone1,2` for the **iPhone 3G**
- `iPhone2,1` for the **iPhone 3GS**
- `iPhone3,1` or `iPhone3,2` for the **iPhone 4**
- `iPhone4,1` for the **iPhone 4S**
- `iPhone5,1` or `iPhone5,2` for the **iPhone 5**

Note that the number in front of the comma of the iPhone 4 platform is actually **3**, not 4.
Using this string you can isolate this number and check if it is greater than or equal to 3:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]) {
    if ([[[platform componentsSeparatedByString:@","][0] substringFromIndex:6] intValue] >= 3) {
        // Device is iPhone 4 or newer
    } else {
        // Device is older than iPhone 4
    }
}
```

**However:** You can actually check the screen's scale, since the iPhone 4 is the first iPhone with a retina display:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]  // Returns 2.0f on the iPhone 4 and newer and 1.0f on older devices
```