# What is platform string for iPhone 5S & 5C?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, iphone-5

I know that someone was able to dig out iphone6,1 platform string from IOS 7 code. However, I don't know what it maps to iPhone 5S or 5C.

If anyone has early access to iPhone 5S/5C, please post platform string for everyone.

For more info on platform string, see these links [theiphonewiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Models), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505414/whats-the-device-code-platform-string-for-iphone-5-ipod-touch-5) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742917/identify-iphones-version/15744956#15744956)

Comment: My bet goes on iphone6,1 being iPhone 5S and iPhone 5C having the same one as iPhone 5

Comment: @mindw0rk 5C is a new piece of hardware, it'll at least get a minor bump (5,3). But I'd bet C gets 6,1 and S gets 6,2

Comment: iPhone 5 has 2 variants: 5,1 & 5,2. Not sure if Apple is doing the same w/ 5S & 5C. If so, we'll have 4 variants !

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- iPhone6,1 = iPhone 5S GSM
- iPhone6,2 = iPhone 5S Global
- iPhone5,3 = iPhone 5C GSM
- iPhone5,4 = iPhone 5C Global

Code:

```
if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPhone5,3"])            return @"iPhone 5C (GSM)";
if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPhone5,4"])            return @"iPhone 5C (Global)";
if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPhone6,1"])            return @"iPhone 5S (GSM)";
if ([platform hasPrefix:@"iPhone6,2"])            return @"iPhone 5S (Global)";
```